# registerMediaButtonEventReceiver / handling volume buttons issue

Tags: android

In my application I need to process physical button events such as volume button clicks. For that I'm using audiomanager's registerMediaButtonEventReceiver method. There's an [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html) relevant to my situation, though I can't get it working.

Here's code I'm using:

```
public class VolumeBroadcastActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        manager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), RemoteControlReceiver.class.getName()));
    }

    public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(VolumeBroadcastActivity.this, "1",1).show();
            if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            }
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="localhost.volume.broadcast"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".VolumeBroadcastActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="RemoteControlReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Which android version has been used?

Answer (score 1):

Your `RemoteControlReceiver` class is an inner class of `VolumeBroadcastActivity`. Your manifest doesn't say so and I don't think it could. Make it a regular class and precede its `android:name` with a dot.

Comment: Manifest can contain inner classes using normal Java syntax like : ".ParentClass$Innerclass"

Answer (score 0):

You might need this permission (declare in manifest):
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"