# How do I register in manifest an *inner* MEDIA_BUTTON BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-audiomanager

I [managed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15057291/636571) to get my headset buttons get recognized by my app when pressed, but one of the buttons needs to call a method that's in MyCustomActivity. The problem is onReceive's 1st parameter is a Context that cannot be cast to Activity and so I am forced to implement my BroadcastReceiver as an inner class inside MyCustomActivity.

So far so good but how do I register this inner MediaButtonEventReceiver in the manifest?

For the independent class, this was simple:

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

What is the trick/syntax to do the same for MyCustomActivity's mReceiver?

```
  private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
         // ...
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't, if it's meant to be part of the Activity, you register it dynamically:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle b)
{
  super.onCreate (b);
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);    
  filter.setPriority(10000);  
  receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
      // ...
    }
  };
  registerReceiver (receiver, filter);
}
```

Then don't forget to unregister in `onPause()` (to avoid leaking).

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{ 
  try{
    unregisterReceiver (receiver);
  }
  catch (IllegalStateException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  super.onPause();
}
```

This dynamic registration does mean however, that if your Activity isn't in the foreground, the button won't work. You can try unregistering in `onDestroy()` instead, but the surest way to avoid leaking is `onPause()`.

Alternatively, to make the button respond no matter what, consider making a Service, and having that register your receiver.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that I tried this but seeing `new BroadcastReceiver()` instantiated again in onCreate(), I am going to try this one more time and report back how it worked. +1 for now.

Comment: Strange. I tried this approach but it doesn't work for some reason. What am I missing?

Comment: @an00b are you leaving the Activity? Remember we're unregistering in `onPause()` to avoid leaking. Also not working as in compiles but doesn't do anything when ran? I recomment making a Toast in `onReceive()` to check if the Receiver is being called at all.

Comment: It compiles & builds fine. It's the receiver that doesn't get called. I'm not leaving the activity.

Comment: @an00b maybe what CommonsWare is referring to is something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074345/registermediabuttoneventreceiver-handling-volume-buttons-issue) question. `AudioManager#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()` And I don't really see what `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` does differently on account of that being the static variable that holds the String `"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"`. Still worth a try though.

Comment: It's the `filter.setPriority(10000);` that eventually did the trick. Interesting. Plus the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` instead of `MEDIA_BUTTON`, of course.

Comment: @an00b hmm, I wonder why this is an ordered broadcast, i'd expect it to be unordered. But nice that you found that out :D Hopefully this will help more people.

Comment: @A--C my guess why it is ordered is so that say answering/ending a phone call takes precedence over starting/pausing music.

Comment: BTW, that above posted code works great in Android 2.x but [doesn't work in Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13576130/636571). Android Fragmentation Uggrrr...

Comment: @an00b This is interesting. I guess you can make the receiver start the Activity with with the singleTop flag so that the new Intent gets routed to `onNewIntent()` and update the UI There.

Comment: @A--C Due to the fact that your wonderful solution doesn't work in 4.1, I am [still searching for a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15102028/636571) (or workaround). Do you have additional suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @an00b might be wasteful, but have **this** Receiver make a *custom* broadcast for *another* BroadCastReceiver implemented by your Activity.

Comment: It's not wasteful if this is the only way to solve this problem. :) Why did Google choose to make our lives so miserable by eliminating goodies that were available in Android 2.x?

Comment: @an00b You don't by any chance have your updated 4.1 code readily avaialble as a project of some sort? I'm on a custom ROM and the media button refuses to work, so I need someone's working implementation to check :)

Answer (score 1):

> So far so good but how do I register this inner MediaButtonEventReceiver in the manifest?

You can't. You can register it dynamically by calling `registerReceiver()` on the activity, though.

Comment: Ouch! I thought that would be the case, so I tried the tip provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4805733/636571) but for some reason it didn't work. Must I `new BroadcastReceiver()` in onCreate() or can I do it when initializing a private data member mReceiver?

Comment: @an00b: Either way works. Usually I set up a private data member for the receiver.

Comment: private data member for the receiver that's what I have too, but none of the 2 approaches work. I may be missing something simple but I don't know what it is. The key presses do not get directed to my inner receiver as in the standalone one.

Comment: @an00b: The media button may be special. Check out `AudioManager` -- I seem to recall there are some things you need to set up on there to get control from a running app. Normally, A--C's approach works fine.

Comment: I suspected so. Perhaps I should be using a receiver class other than BroadcastReceiver? Is there a "MediaButtonEventReceiver"? Also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10917769/636571) says "use ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON instead of MEDIA_BUTTON".

Comment: @an00b: Not that I am aware of.